# SQL: like v. equals performance comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a large table (100 million rows) which is properly indexed in a traditional RDBMS system (Oracle, MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.).  I would like to perform a SELECT query which can be formulated with either of the following criteria options:

One that can be represented by a single criteria:

```
LIKE "T40%"
```

which only looks for matches at the beginning of the string field due to the wildcard

or

One that requires a list of say 200 exact criteria:

```
WHERE IN("T40.x21","T40.x32","T40.x43")
```

etc.

All other things being equal. Which should I expect to be more performant?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: Usually, `LIKE` with trailing % can make use of the index and cut down the search time dramatically.  But as this is implementation dependent, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Proper answer: It depends.

Comment: it will also perform better with a tigher pattern.  if it will only ever be `T40.x##` then something like `T40.x??` or `T40.x[0-9][0-9]` would be better. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql

Comment: Personally I would not expect any significant difference. The DBs you mention all have EXPLAIN or similar capabilities & the only way to be sure it to compare the results of that for each query (something you would only do if your preferred approach actually caused performance problems in the first place).

Comment: I think different engines may perform differently. This is an interesting question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both queries return the same set of rows (i.e. the list of items that you supply in the `IN` expression is exhaustive) you should expect almost identical performance, perhaps with some advantage for the `LIKE` query.

- RDBMS engines have been using index searches for begins-with `LIKE` queries, so `LIKE 'T40%'` will produce records after an index search
- Your `IN` query would be optimized for index search as well, perhaps giving RDBMS a tighter lower and upper bounds. However, there would be an additional filtering step to eliminate records outside your `IN` list, which is a waste of CPU cycles under the assumption that all rows would be returned anyway.

In case you'd parameterize your query, the second query becomes harder to pass to an RDBMS from your host program. All other things being equal, I would use `LIKE`.

Comment: This matches my experiences and intuition as well for this very specific use case.  If it was not a begins-with LIKE, you would definitely end up taking a big performance hit by not being able to utilize index searches as well.

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest to go with LIKE operator because the ESCAPE OPTION Has to be used along with '\' symbol to increase the exact matching the character string.